# SqlCommand.Parameters.Add not converting parameters when trying to do DELETE statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, sqlcommand

I am doing an INSERT query to a db with the following code which works fine.

```cs
public int InsertPerson(Person person, out string errormsg)
{
    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();

    dbConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=PersonDB;Integrated Security=True";

    String sqlstring = "INSERT INTO PersonTable ( FirstName, LastName ) VALUES ( @firstname, @lastname )";
    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, dbConnection);

    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = person.FirstName;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = person.LastName;

    try
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        
        int i = 0;
        i = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        if (i == 1) 
        { 
            errormsg = ""; 
        }
        else
        {
            errormsg = "Could not add person";
        }

        return i;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errormsg = e.Message;
        return 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

However when I try to use the logic in a DELETE query it does not convert the `@firstname` and `@lastname` to the parameter values passed to the method call.

```cs
public int DeletePerson(Person person, out string errormsg)
{
    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();

    dbConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=PersonDB;Integrated Security=True";

    String sqlstring = "DELETE FROM PersonTable WHERE FirstName = @firstname AND LastName = @lastname";

    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, dbConnection);

    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = person.FirstName;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = person.LastName;

    try
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        int i = 0;
        i = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (i == 1)
        {
            errormsg = "";
        }
        else
        {
            //errormsg = "Could not delete person";
            errormsg = sqlstring;
        }

        return i;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errormsg = e.Message;
        return 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

The query that is created from the DELETE method looks like this `DELETE FROM PersonTable WHERE FirstName = @firstname AND LastName = @lastname`

It works fine when I hardcode the SQL query but not when I use the attributes of the Person parameter as parts of the query..

Comment: "The query that is created from the DELETE method looks like this" Where are you seeing this? You won't see the values injected except perhaps in some SQL logs. Are you seeing the values replaced with the INSERT query?

Comment: `i = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`  Are you saying i = 0?  Or is there an exception?  If the hardcoded version works, then you have to use the debugger to see what the difference is.  Although it seemingly works, I would prefer matching the parameter name: `dbCommand.Parameters.Add("FirstName"...` should be `dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname"...` etc.

Comment: @DStanley in the ```else``` clause in the ```try``` clause I put the sqlstring into errormsg that is returned by the method.

Comment: Can you confirm the `person` object is not NULL, and its first and last name are not longer than 30 characters?

Comment: Try including the @ symbol in the variable name and using the same case like dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname",...

Comment: @LarsTech i = 0 is just the instantiation allthough unneccesary.. ```dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();``` is supposed to return 1 if it is successful i believe. Atleast it does so in my insert statement

Comment: @shurda That's what I'm asking.  Is i equal to 0 or 1?  What value is `dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` returning?

Comment: Ooooh right @LarsTech my mistake, It doesn't return 1 if successful it returns the amount of affected rows or something - when I changed the paramter name from "FirstName" to "@firstname" it works and returns the amount of posts that were deleted :D Could you possibly explain why?

Comment: @MikeFisher If the @ is not included in the name it will be automatically added.  Note they don't use the @ in the names for the insert and that works just fine.  I'm guessing the case also doesn't matter based on that.

Answer (score 4):

You may misunderstand how parameters work. The value is not "replaced" in the SQL statement. The SQL statement is sent *as-is* with the parameter values provided separately. So you won't see a SQL string on the client side with the values replaced.

In other words, the value of `sqlstring` does not change. If that's what you're looking at then it won't tell you anything. Something else is wrong - either that name combination is not found in the DB, or there's some difference in casing, whitespace, etc.

Comment: Oh ok, my mistake :) Thanks for the clarification!